# Javascript超初心者です

Tags: javascript

初めまして、質問なんですが
サイコロを振り、出た目を２ｘ＋５して結果が１００以下の場合もう一度２ｘ＋５をし、
結果が１００を超えたらその結果と何回計算したかを出力しろ

という問題なんですがランダムな数字を生成することはできました。
しかしその先で躓いてしまい、中々うまくいきません。
どなたかアドバイスを下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

とりあえず書いてみたソースです。

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    function GetRandomNumber() {
       var randnum = Math.floor( Math.random() * 9 );
       document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = randnum;
    }
    // -->
    var a = 0;
    var count = 0;
    var y = randnum;

    while(randnum < 100) {
      if(randnum > 100) {
        document.write(a+count+"回目です");
      }
      a += 2 * (y) + 5
      ++count;
    }
    </script>
    <p>
       <input type="button" value="サイコロ" onclick="GetRandomNumber();">
    </p>
    <p>
       出た目： <span id="sample">***</span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: タイトルを質問の内容を端的に表すものに変更した方が良いと思います。

Comment: 何が上手くいかないか整理してもらえますか。また、２ｘ＋５とはどういう意味ですか？

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` は、ページを構成する時に使いますので、
ボタンを押した時を起点に動作するようにする必要があります。
例えば以下のような感じにします。

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script>
    function Dice() {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 ) + 1;
    }

    function DoIt() {
        var x = Dice();
        var count = 0;
        do {
            x = 2*x + 5;
            ++count;
        }while(x <= 100);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
            x + "になるまで" + count + "回計算しました。";
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
       <button type="button" onclick="DoIt()">実行</button>
    </p>
    <p>
       結果： <span id="result"></span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。
よく分かりました！

Comment: @user10383  この回答で満足されたのであれば[承認](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1736/5044)下さい。